# Jenkins: attach multiple files in same email using emailext attachmentsPattern

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We are trying to use Jenkins pipeline and using the following function:

```
emailext attachmentsPattern: "${env.LOG_FILE}" , "${env.PASSED_SOURCES_LOG}", "${env.FAILED_SOURCES_LOG}",
body: "Hi,\nThe nightly integration tests run is completed. Please find the log attached to this email.",
subject: "NIGHTLY INTEGRATION TESTS RUN - ${BUILD_NUMBER}",
to: "${env.EMAIL}"
```

Unfortunatelly I could not find a way to put these multiple files in same email. It outputs error.

Would someone know how to declare it properly?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attachmentsPattern takes an Ant file pattern so perhaps something like:

```
**/*.log
```

would work. Or you could collect the files by reading them and writing them to a single file and then attach that.